# About the condition $\ker(B_h) \subset \ker(B)$ in mixed finite elements formulation

Tags: finite-element, numerics, navier-stokes, saddlepoint, mixed-formulation

I'm studying mixed finite elements. The problem is a classical saddle-point one: we seek for $(u,p)$ in $V \times Q$:
$$A u + B^t p = f$$
$$Bu = g$$
where $A: V \rightarrow V', B:V \rightarrow Q'$  and $V,Q$ are Hilbert spaces. For this problem, we have the inf-sup conditions on $A$ and $B$ that essentially tell us that the problem is well posed.

As far as I understand, the issue one the discrete level (in contrast to what happens for Poisson equation, and other coercive problems) is that if we consider $V_h \subset V$ and $Q_h \subset Q$ as finite dimensional spaces in which we seek the solution, then we can no more apply the continuous properties to the discrete problem because for instance $$\ker(B_h) \not \subset \ker(B)$$ in general.

So far so good. Then, while doing the analysis, my professor wrote the following diagriam

[image]
and he said that **we would like to join with dotted arrow and we would like that $B_h$ maps entire $V_h$ into the entire $Q_h'$ and we would like this diagram to commute. He then said that it's trivial if $\ker(B_h) \subset \ker(B)$**.

I really can't understand why the inclusion of the kernels implies the commutativity of the diagram. Any help is highly appreciated, and even an example where $B$ is the usual divergence operator is perfectly fine to me.

---

**EDIT:** Maybe I got the way to go: the diagram commuting means that $$ \Pi_{Q_h'} \circ B =  B_h  \circ \Pi_{V_h}$$

Now, if the $\ker(B_h) \not \subset \ker(B)$, this means there exists a function $v_h \in V_h \subset V$ such that $$B_h v_h = 0$$ and $$B v_h \ne 0$$

If it commutes, it should hold:$$ B_h \Pi_{V_h} v_h=\underbrace{B_h v_h}_{0}  = \Pi_{Q_h'} \underbrace{B v_h}_{\ne 0} \ne 0$$

which is clearly false. In the first equality I used the fact that $v_h$ is of course not affected by the projection. What do you think ? I think that something more can surely be said. Please feel free to add more things about this

Comment: Nice question -- but I don't understand this either. What does it mean *this arrow exists*. Maybe that $B_h$ together with $V_h$ and $Q_h$ fulfill an *inf-sup* condition with a constant independent of $h$? (That would be the standard requirement for *inf-sup* stable finite elements)

Comment: @Jan I edited the question, maybe now it's more clear. Basically, he said that the condition on the kernels implies that the diagram commutes. It seems to be trivial, but I really don't see how